Using Dictionary Tokens on Internal Link Query Parameters or Anchor Tags
I am on Sitecore XP 10.2 and am trying to figure out the best way so that I can alter the text of the query parameters or anchor tags for a Sitecore Link.  We use GlassMapper, but also have some legacy code that doesn't.  It appears that our custom LinkProvider can only modify the url itself.

What is your use case? That question is a bit open ended as it is. What are you trying to achieve?

@RichardSeal...We have a blog with sections in it for every US State.  I want someone to be insert a link to an internal item that will then append the state's name in the anchor tag (https://www.example.com/item#Pennsylvania) based on the geolocation they came from.  So in sitecore, the item would have a link of https://www.example.com and the anchor property would be "{0:StateName}" (or something similar).  We could create 51 different personalization tests in the page, but that would be excessive.

@AronBender In case I understand correctly you are looking for adding the anchor tag automatically based on geolocation on blog links on your website?

@ckhanna...yes, but via a Dictionary token.  I don't want to have to touch every potential component that uses links.  I want to make sure that any link field we use can insert a variable of sorts to populate it if necessary.  We do this with rich text fields (html), but I'm not sure how to do this with links themselves.

In order to replace the anchor tag on the links with the state name gathered from Sitecore Geolocation service, you will need to extend the processor inside the renderField pipeline as below.

Create the processor as below, that converts the dictionary token for state, inside the anchor attribute in the General Link field.

using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Sitecore.Analytics;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;
using System.Linq;

public class ReplaceGeoLocationTokenInGeneralLink
{
   public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
   {
     if (!Tracker.IsActive || Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction == null || !Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.HasGeoIpData)
     {
        return;
     }

     if (args.FieldTypeKey == "general link")
     {
        string state = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.GeoData.Region;
        var linkHtml = args.Result.FirstPart;
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(linkHtml);
        var anchorNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
        if (anchorNodes != null && anchorNodes.Any())
        {
           foreach (var anchorNode in anchorNodes)
           {
              var anchorAttribute = anchorNode.Attributes.Where(x => x.Name.Equals("href"))?.FirstOrDefault();
              if(anchorAttribute != null && anchorAttribute.Value.Contains("{{statename}}"))
              {
                 anchorAttribute.Value = anchorAttribute.Value.Replace("{{statename}}", state);
              }
           }
           args.Result.FirstPart = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
        }
     }
  }
}


Patch the above processor created, after the GetInternalLinkFieldValue processor inside the renderField pipleine as below.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>
        <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetInternalLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="SitecoreCustomExtensions.Pipelines.ReplaceGeoLocationTokenInGeneralLink,SitecoreCustomExtensions" resolve="true" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Using above way, the state dictionary token inside the anchor attribute in the General Link field, can be dynamically replaced with the region calculated from Sitecore Geolocation service.
Note: The dictionary token for the state inside the General link field can be configured as below.

Update:
In case the links are rendered using Glass Mapper, you can pass the anchor attribute to the RenderLink function as below.
@{
  string statename = string.Empty.
  if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction != null && Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.HasGeoIpData)
  {
   statename = Tracker.Current.Session.Interaction.GeoData.Region;
  }
}

@if(Model.Link!=null && Model.Link.Anchor.Contains("{{statename}}")){
  @Html.Glass().RenderLink(Model, m => m.Link, new { @anchor = statename }, true)
}else{
  @Html.Glass().RenderLink(Model, m => m.Link, new{ }, true)
}

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

I tried this (though much more simplistic for my first test) and it appears that links do not go through my processor at all.  I logged FIrstPart to my console (and LastPart just in case) and none of the links show up. The only thing I see in the logs are rich text fields going through the processor

Your solution would (likely work).  I didn't mention that we use GlassMapper because I thought it wouldn't be relevant.  Apparently it is relevant and I need to override that.

yes @AronBender in case you are using GlassMapper the renderfield pipeline is not called when you are not in experience editor mode. In this case you can pass anchor as an attribute to the RenderLink function, to transform the links. I have uploaded the approach for the same above. Let me know in case you face any issues.

If you’re using GlassMapper, you can do something similar with query parameters by using GlassHtml and Translate.Text() to inject dynamic values into links:
var link = glassHtml.Editable(item, x => x.LinkField);
var dictionaryText = Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("your-dictionary-token");
var modifiedLink = $"{link}?param={dictionaryText}";

or
If you have a custom LinkProvider in Sitecore and want it to dynamically inject query parameters or anchor tag text, you could modify your GetUrl() method within the provider to include dictionary tokens:
public override string GetUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
{
    var url = base.GetUrl(item, options);
    var dictionaryText = Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text("your-dictionary-token");

    return $"{url}?param={dictionaryText}";
}

